# Limit query result

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Given the schema and data below,

```
CREATE TABLE `Payroll` (
      `payId` int,
      `payName` varchar(20),
      `groupId` int,
      `startDate` date ,
      `endDate` date,
      `paymentDate` date
    );
    
    insert into Payroll values
    (20,'June A',2,'2022-06-01','2022-06-30','2022-06-30'),
    (21,'July A',2,'2022-07-01','2022-07-31','2022-07-31'),
    (17,'April A',1,'2022-04-01','2022-04-30','2022-04-30'),
    (18,'May A',1,'2022-05-01','2022-05-31','2022-05-31'),
    (19,'July B',1,'2022-07-01','2022-07-31','2022-07-31')
    ;
    
    CREATE TABLE `PayrollItems` (
        `payId` int NOT NULL,
        `employeeId` int ,
        `payCategory` varchar(45) ,
        `value` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL  
    );
    
    insert into PayrollItems values
    (20,12,'salary',200),
    (20,12,'housing',500),
    (20,13,'salary',400),
    (20,14,'salary',1300),
    (21,12,'salary',200),
    (21,12,'housing',500),
    (21,13,'salary',400),
    (21,14,'salary',1300),
    (18,13,'salary',400),
    (18,13,'housing',1300),
    (19,14,'salary',500),
    (19,14,'housing',1200),
    (17,14,'salary',700),
    (17,14,'housing',1000)
    ;
```

How should i enhance the below query so that i get the previous payid row only, previous pay id would be a payid that has the same group id but a payment date dated prior, having said that i would want the one payid dated prior.

```
SELECT distinct
    a.payId,a.payName, b.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Payroll.payId,
            employeeId,
  payName,
            groupId,
            paymentDate,
            SUM(value * (payCategory = 'housing')) housing,
            SUM(value * (payCategory = 'salary')) salary
    FROM
        PayrollItems
    JOIN Payroll ON (Payroll.payid = PayrollItems.payId)
    GROUP BY Payroll.payId , employeeId , groupId , paymentDate,payName) a
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
            Payroll.payId,
            employeeId,
            payName,
            groupId,
            max(paymentDate) paymentDate,
            SUM(value * (payCategory = 'housing')) housing,
            SUM(value * (payCategory = 'salary')) salary
    FROM
        PayrollItems
    JOIN Payroll ON (Payroll.payid = PayrollItems.payId)
    GROUP BY Payroll.payId , employeeId , groupId , paymentDate,payName) b ON b.groupId = a.groupId
        AND b.paymentDate < a.paymentDate
  order by a.payId,b.payId,b.employeeId
;
```

In the result shown below i **do not** need the row marked in red to appear

[image]

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CbBocTXq)

Comment: Can you explain what your query is supposed to do?

Comment: the query is supposed to give payid with adjacent records for payids that are dated prior to it. The issue with this query is that it gives all records having a payment date less than whereas i only want the first record dated prior.

Comment: Are you sure payId=19 shouldn't be matched with payId=17? They reference the same employeeId=14, while payId=18 references employeeId=13. Is this correct? When you match payId = 20 with payId = 21, you couple same employeeId together.

Comment: Yes it should not match with 17. The query should just give back the result of the ONE payid found prior to it, given they both have the same groupid

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to learn how to use [MySQL 8.0 window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).

```
mysql> select payId, lag(payId) over (partition by groupId order by payId) as prevPayId 
  from Payroll;
+-------+-----------+
| payId | prevPayId |
+-------+-----------+
|    17 |      NULL |
|    18 |        17 |
|    19 |        18 |
|    20 |      NULL |
|    21 |        20 |
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Some use of window functions could probably have helped your other question earlier today. So I encourage you to study window functions in general, and practice them so you know how to utilize them in different query cases.

Comment: Thank you yes, but a bit pressed for time atm. I see your answer seems to take into consideration the groupId whereas the paymentDate is key too.

Comment: It's only meant as a demo of the window function. I'm not attempting to give you a full solution, that's your job.